# How to update a react component's state from another file?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

In my application, I have a text and a list which uses react-virtualized for rendering a large list of items, each item having a detailed description about some of the words in the text. Works very good, but what I need is when I click on an area in the text, the list to be re-rendered so that the corresponding item will be shown

```
class VirtualizedList extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scrollToIndex: 0
    };
    this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
    this.scrollToIndex = this.scrollToIndex.bind(this);
  }

renderItem ({
  key = this.props.data[index].key,
  index,
  parent,
  style,
  itemToRender = this.props.data[index]
}) {
  return (
    <CellMeasurer 
    cache={cache}
    columnIndex={0}
    key={key}
    parent={parent}
    rowIndex={index}
  >
      <div
        style={style}
      >
        {index}
        {itemToRender}
      </div>

      </CellMeasurer>
  )
}
scrollToIndex(index) {
    this.setState({
      scrollToIndex: index
    });
}

render() {    

return (      
  <AutoSizer>
      {
        ({ width, height }) => (
          <List
            width={width}
            height={height}
            rowCount={this.props.data.length}
            deferredMeasurementCache={cache}
            rowHeight={cache.rowHeight}
            rowRenderer={this.renderItem}
            scrollToIndex={this.state.scrollToIndex}
          />          
        )
      }
      </AutoSizer>
);
}
};

export default VirtualizedList;
```

in it's parent it's called like this:

```
<VirtualizedList
    data={listItems} >     
</VirtualizedList>
```

I created the 
    scrollToIndex() 
method so I can call it and update VirtualizedList's state and so re-rendering the list to the specified index, but I get this warning:
    setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component...

I call the method like this (to scroll the list to include the 10th item):

```
const listInstance = new VirtualizedList;
      listInstance.scrollToIndex(9);
```

any help or recommendation on how to implement this would be highly appreciated.
thank you!

Comment: You are calling scrollToIndex before the component is mounted. Therefore you are getting the warning. I would suggest that you use a prop instead.

Comment: no, the component is actually mounted, the list is displayed.. I will try updating the props. thank you

Comment: could I update a prop in scrollToIndex ? I tried this.props.index = index instead of setState, but I get Cannot set property 'index' of undefined error.

Comment: What you want is a controlled component with the scrolIIndex being the value controlled by the parent. Just add scrollIndex as a prop to your `VirtualizedList` Component. `<VirtualizedList data={listItems}> scrollIndex={<your scroll value>} ...`  In your VirtualizedList you can just use that value if it is passed in by the parent: `<List scrollToIndex={this.props.scrollIndex || this.state.scrollToIndex} ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `const listInstance = new VirtualizedList;
>         listInstance.scrollToIndex(9);`

You can't do that - this won't be the same instance, not rendered/mounted etc.

You need to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up) - communicate by parent.

Just pass `scrollToIndex` from parent as prop:

```
<VirtualizedList
  data={listItems}
  scrollToIndex={someSelectedIndexInParent}
/>
```

You can use PureComponent

```
class VirtualizedList extends PureComponent{
```

it will be rerendered on prop change.

Of course use `this.props` in `<List`

```
scrollToIndex={this.props.scrollToIndex}
```

Comment: thank you, I did just that, passing the new index as prop from the parent worked perfectly for my case. a little ashamed I din't think at that from the start...